# How can I use tflint on VSCode with HashiCorp Terraform plugin?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terraform

I'm trying to use tflint on VSCode, but can't configure it properly.
On my terminal, both `terraform` and `tflint` works well.

```
terraform --version
Terraform v0.12.28

tflint --version
TFLint version 0.17.0

which tflint
/usr/local/bin/tflint
```

But on VSCode, linting does not work.
I've installed HashiCorp Terraform plugin v2.0.2, and enabled terraform language server. Now I checked my `setting.json`. Many articles on the Internet says we can configure it on `terraform.lintPath` fiels, but there isn't any such a field.

```
{
  "editor.tabSize": 2,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "terraform.languageServer": {},
}
```

I tried to add `terraform.lintPath` inside or outside `terraform.languageServer`, but it failed.  Is there any way to check path that VSCode can refer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Terraform plugin for Visual Studio Code no longer supports `tflint` since v2.

You can see the difference in supported features in the README for each version. The [v1.4.0 release](https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform/blob/v1.4.0/README.md) shows the following features:

> - Auto-completion support
>
>   1. `Terraform` high level types `(variable, resource, data, module ...)` auto completion support.
>   2. `resource` types `(aws_dynamodb_table ...)` auto completion support for `aws`, `azure`, `datadog`, `google`, `oci` and `openstack`
>   3. `resource | data | module | output | variable` property types auto completion support
>   4. `resource | data` 1-level nested block property types auto completion support
> - Syntax highlighting for `.tf` and `.tfvars` files (and `.hcl`)
> - Automatic formatting using `terraform fmt`
> - Automatically closes braces and quotes
> - Adds a command for running `terraform validate`
> - Linting support with the help of [tflint](https://github.com/wata727/tflint)
> - Browse document symbols
> - Browse workspace symbols
> - Peek definition
> - Goto definition
> - Find references
> - Completion for variables and outputs
> - Rename variables, resource, and data types and all references
> - Show variable values on hover
> - CodeLens shows if a section is referenced

While the [v2 release](https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform/blob/v2.0.0/README.md) shows these features:

> - Manages installation and updates of the [Terraform Language Server (terraform-ls)](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-ls), exposing
>   its features:
>
>   - Initialized provider completion (resource names, data source names, attribute names)
> - Includes syntax highlighting for `.tf` and `.tfvars` files (and `.hcl`) -- including all syntax changes new to Terraform 0.12
> - Closes braces and quotes
> - Includes `for_each` and `variable` syntax shortcuts (`fore`, `vare`, `varm`)

There's [an issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/vscode-terraform/issues/337) tracking re-adding `tflint` support but there's not been any work done on this just yet.

Comment: Wow really    
Now I understand the situation. Thanks.